# how to change mysql sql mode after installation

Tags: mysql

i have mysql installed and table created. i want to remove `strict_trans_tables` from sql mode, how to do that? I tried the fonllowing:
1) go to phpmyadmin variable and edit sql mode, but mysql reset it back to default value

2) followed https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting
and tried in command line to reset sql mode:

```
sudo mysqld --sql mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

3) located file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and tried to change setting there, but didn't find any sql mode info.

Can i change sql mode after installation? how?

Comment: it possible that is the default mode, so there are no entry used in my.cnf. You can set it in my.cnf or via query like : SET sql_mode='.......';

Answer (score 1):

In your mysql console change your sql_mode  (eg for global change)

```
 SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

but before change read carefully  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html

Comment: He wanted a permanent solution, this is again only temporary.

Answer (score 1):

> 3) located file /etc/mysql/my.cnf and tried to change setting there, but didn't find any sql mode info

If you do not have any sql mode set in the file, just add new line:

```
sql_mode="NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

As of MySQL 5.7.x, the default sql mode includes **ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY**. But before 5.7.5, in MySql `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` was not enabled by default.

**ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY**: Non-deterministic grouping queries will be rejected

For more details check the documentation of [sql_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

Follow the below methods to modify the **sql_mode**

**Method 1:**

Check default value of **sql_mode**:

```
SELECT @@sql_mode
```

Remove `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` from console by executing below query:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

**Method 2:**

Access phpmyadmin for editing your `sql_mode`

- Login on phpmyadmin and open localhost
- Top on **Variables** present on the top in menu items and search out for **sql mode**
- Click on edit button to remove `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` and save
  [image: sql mode settings in phpmyadmin]

**Restart MySQL server**

```
sudo service mysql restart OR Logout `phpmyadmin` and login again.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a permanent solution for this

```
set PERSIST sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

[Step By step tutorial given below](https://www.tutorialslides.com/how-to-troubleshoot-1227-error-in-phpmyadmin-access-denied-for-changing-sql_mode-variable-without-super-or-system_variables_admin-privileges-cloudpanel/)