# UNISERVER STRICT TABLE

Tags: php, mysql

i use Uniserver Zero XIV

this Uniserver can switch php version ( i have 2 version php 7.4 and php 5.6)
but when i go phpmyAdmin must use php 7.4,

when i use php 5.6 still can connect database but have following errors
"Field 'xxx' doesn't have a default value"

when i set sql mode= ''; (saved) (php 7.4) then restart apache and mysql (switch php 5.6)
it wont save, the value sql mode before editing still exist, cant fix the error;

if i open my.ini there is no sql mode to change

Comment: @JeleanThomas no sir

Comment: Where did you put `set sql mode= '';`?

Comment: SET GLOBAL sql_mode = ''; in SQL tab phpmyadmin @JeleanThomas

Comment: That's not setting it permanently. It will disappear right after restart. You need to add it into `my.ini` Follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51143053/3925125

Comment: @JeleanThomas omg, i'm so bad, It works, thank you sir